# windows azure cspack error The system ca nnot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MSBuildTask

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure

Hello I am trying to package an azure cloud solution on a windows 2008 server machine from the commandline using cspack.exe, the azur packaging tool basically crashes with the error message below

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or ass
embly 'Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MSBuildTasks, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neu
tral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system ca
nnot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MSBuildTasks, Version=1.0.0.0, Cultur
e=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.Packaging.Program.Main(String[] args)

The assembly Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MSBuildTasks is at the location C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Cloud Service\1.0\Visual Studio 10.0, so Im not sure why it is not being found

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does your environment have the proper paths as the Azure command line  under program files sets them up?

Comment: Hi Jeffery , Thanks for your suggestion, I fixed this eventually by locating the assemblies and installing them in the gac, these assemblies are part of the azure sdk and i would have thought that they would be installed in the gac by default

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this eventually by locating the assemblies and installing them in the gac, these assemblies are part of the azure sdk and i would have thought that they would be installed in the gac by default